# Mount NTFS Partition in Linux Mint 19.1 with permissions

Tags: partitioning, permissions, linux-mint, ntfs

Mounting itself is not a problem, but the permissions are not correct.

I have created a *.NTFS-3g\UserMapping* on the root of my NTFS partition. It contains:

```
# Generated by ntfsusermap for Linux, v 1.2.0
1000:1000:S-1-5-21-1623860131-3949047850-1793866259-1002
```

In Addition I habe created an entry in */etc/fstab*.

```
UUID=xxxx /media/windows auto defaults 0 0
```

I already played around with umask.

If I create a file from Linux at /media/windows/Users/myuser/Downloads it has not only the standard windows permission, but also it has an Entry for Everybody(Jeder).
Also if I play around with umask or manually set `chmod 660` the entry for Everybody stays and has special permissions.
Also the other Windows rights are not correct. A file created in Windows has Full Access setting for the user, administrators, and system.
A file created under Linux has the setting Special for the three users/groups.

Is it possible to set the rights exactly the same?

Answer (score 2):

You have to be sure that the fs gets mounted with the proper driver in order to handle the user mapping, to do this specify "ntfs-3g" instead of "auto". Overmore, you have to give the "permissions" option to let the driver to use the user mapping. Also set the "windows_names" option to avoid the creation of file with names Windows can't handle.

The mount line should be like this one:

```
UUID=xxxx /media/windows ntfs-3g defaults,permissions,windows_names 0 0
```

If you want to handle the ACLs you have to use the "acl" option instead of the "permissions" option. You can then handle the single user permissions with the getfacl and setfacl commands.

Answer (score 1):

The folder needs to be `.NTFS-3G` (all uppercase)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).